# Filter chunks of elements from dictionary of [String:[Any]] - Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has a list of elements as a value for each key. The number of elements in all lists will always be equal. The dictionary looks something like this:

```
[
"Product_ID": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
"Product_Name": [Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Name5, Name6, Name7, Name8, Name9, Name10],
"Product_Quantity": [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
]
```

I want to filter out **chunks of up to 5 elements from each key** and return the filtered dictionary. So for each iteration, this is what I want:

First iteration:

```
[
"Product_ID": [1,2,3,4,5],
"Product_Name": [Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4, Name5],
"Product_Quantity": [10,20,30,40,50]
]
```

Second iteration:

```
[
"Product_ID": [6,7,8,9,10],
"Product_Name": [Name6, Name7, Name8, Name9, Name10],
"Product_Quantity": [60,70,80,90,100]
]
```

I know this can be done using a for loop but I want to find a better way of doing this

**NOTE:** Incase there are less than 5 elements left for a given iteration, the code should return that many elements. In other words, the number of elements doesn't have to be a multiple of 5 and hence code shouldn't crash.

Comment: You should use a struct instead having the the tree keys as properties instead and then use an array of that struct. This would make things much easier for you

Comment: @JoakimDanielson So what you're suggesting is a key:value pair of each element? For instance [ ["Product_ID": 6, "Product_Name": Name6, "Product_Quantity": 60], ["Product_ID": 7, "Product_Name": Name7, "Product_Quantity": 70] ... ]?
If that's what you are suggesting then how do I get it in the format I have mentioned above?

Comment: No, I am suggesting you create a `struct`.